# WCF REST service for images doesn't work on Azure?

Tags: wcf, image, rest, azure, stream

I have a working WCF REST service (.NET 4.0) for down-streaming the images. But when this service is published to the Azure Website (.NET 4.5) the images loaded are randomly corrupt. This never happens locally, or even on a within a domain.

On Azure it's not consistent. Sometimes it loads, sometimes it doesn't. You can check out the corruption here:

http://telproabrdev.azurewebsites.net/logo/vyrobce/get?id=4bced4ee-7162-45a3-a495-7764305e2d56&format=PNG

This is my code (basically):

Contract:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "get?id={id}&format={format}", 
    RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, 
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, 
    BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
Stream GetImage(String id, String format);
```

Implementation:

```
public Stream GetImage(String id, String format)
{
   // stuff, stuff, stuff

   using (Stream original = GetImageStream())
   {
       Stream result = CreateThumbnailStream(original, width, height);
       result.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
       return result;
   }
} 

private Stream GetImageStream() 
{
    Bitmap copy = new Bitmap(Resource.SomePicture);
    Stream result = new MemoryStream();
    image.Save(result, ImageFormat.Png);
    return result;
}

private Stream CreateThumbnailStream(Image image, Int32 width, Int32 height)
{
    Image image = Image.FromStream(stream);
    Image result = new Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

    // shrinking routine skipped for brevity

    return result;
}
```

So far, I've tried this:

1. removing all the 'usings' -> no effect (but probable memory leak)
2. wrapping the MemoryStream in a BufferedStream -> nope
3. removing Seek() -> no image (as expected)

What I'm I doing wrong? It worked on the different projects (not Azure though). Is the .NET 4.0 vs 4.5 compatibility the culprit?

Comment: The image I'm seeing is cropped too short. Are you sure the height parameter is calculated correctly?

Comment: This is the same service on a different server (without Azure): http://abrtest.aspone.cz/logo/vyrobce/get?id=4bced4ee-7162-45a3-a495-7764305e2d56&format=PNG it works normally. It literally works everywhere (local, domain, other local, two 3rd party web hosting services). I've read about .NET 4.5 streaming incompatibility (buffer vs non-buffered), and I'm wondering, if it can be the cause.

Comment: There is definitely an issue with the Azure-hosted version. It has [(2) **IHDR chunks** in the binary output](http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG-Chunks.html) and it should only have (1) IHDR. There seems to be some duplicate data in the output file stream.

Comment: @SmartK8, There is a similar post here : http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/2bc5e5a6-1971-46cb-8b4f-f1c46130faca. Can you check if message logging enabled in your service? If so try disabling message logging and see if that fixes your problem?

Comment: Praburaj: Thanks, I'm checking it right now. It seems very plausible.

Comment: I've removed the diagnostics and tracing, and it works now. Make it an answer, so I can accept it. I really hope the Microsoft guys will think of some workaround this is really annoying. We're not planning to upgrade to 4.5 anytime soon. Anyway, thanks a lot.